# SVG Arc Menu Can't Create arcs

Tags: xml, html, css, svg, sass

I am trying to create a menu with two arcs as menu items, which then behave as buttons that trigger a radial menu like [this one](http://creative-punch.net/2014/02/making-animated-radial-menu-css3-javascript/).

I've been struggling with these SVG paths forever but just can't get them to behave properly. Both arcs have to be 1/4 of a circle (they have to be placed next to each other eventually, forming 1/2 of a circle). This is what I've got so far: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3t5kynox/).

I believe my intentions are clear enough when I say that I want two arcs (1/4 circle) placed next to each other (creating half a circle).

I'll include the HTML here as well:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

    <path id="a" d="M40 50 A 40 50 0,0,0 80 90 L 80 50 Z" fill="#bf1238"></path>
    <path id="a" d="M120 50 A 120 50 0,0,0 120 90 L 120 50 Z" fill="#bf1238"></path>

</svg>
```

I haven't gotten to the radial menu part yet, as I wanted to get this out of the way first. If you feel like it, feel free to leave any advice on the radial menu, just note I want to do this in plain JS and SCSS.

**FIXED**

I realised, thanks to @Harry, I misunderstood the `A`-syntax in the `d` attribute from `path`. I defined it as the starting point for the curve instead of the `X` and `Y` radius.. This is the code now:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <path id="a" d="M40 50 A 45 45 0,0,0 80 90 L 80 50 Z" fill="#bf1238"></path>
    <path id="a" d="M120 50 A 45 45 0,0,1 80 90 L 80 50 Z" fill="#bf1238"></path>
</svg>
```

I will also update the JSFiddle I made previously so you can see the results!

Comment: I think you haven't understood the `A` command's syntax properly. The first two values are the radius in X and Y directions and not the coordinates of the starting point. Have a look at this MDN page for more details - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d

Comment: @Harry I.. I've been so blind... This was like an instafix to my issue! All I had to do now was change the `sweep-flag` to 1 and I had exactly what I needed! Kudos to you sir!